# Debug chrome on ipad / ios7

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, ios7

I have a web app that runs beautifully on every browser and platform except google chrome on iPad 2 (ios7.0.4), where i get a white page with some elements but not my whole page. That is, both safari and mercury on the same ipad works just fine! And chrome on win/mac/ububtu works flawlessly. I cant run chome on ios simulator. Is there a way to debug CHROME specifically on the ipad, or am i going to have to deconstruct everything and do a billion refreshes to work it out by hand?

Answer (score 0):

[Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) let's you debug your webapp remotely on desktop. jsFiidle is one of the services that uses it. It runs on a server with node.js and any client with WebKit (except Chrome)<sup>[1]</sup>. Refer to their website's documentations for more info.

If you find installing it troublesome, (not recommended but still) you can copy your code to jsFiddle and use their service.

Note 1: By *Chrome* I mean the remote inspector cannot be opened in Chrome. Safari can, however.

[image]

> Though this is convenient for small scripts, larger webpages are not recommended to use this technique (using jsFiddle)

Comment: Well, jsfiddling my app is *utterly* out of the question, its just way too complex, so ill check out the inpector.

Comment: @frumbert - As I said in the answer, if you don't mind installing a remote inspector, you can always use Weinre alone.